# Row By Row ( Without Cursor or Loops)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Here I have sample data of students having RollNumbers and their coursecodes.

```
-------------------------
    Roll      CourseCode
--------------------------
    1011       CS201
    2213       CS201
    3312       CS101
    4000       CS201
    1011       CS101
    5312       ME102
    1011       PT101
    3312      ME102
```

Result should be `Coursecode` and their exam date

e.g (Sort Out Distinct Coursecodes)

First I am picking CS201 and assigning that coursecode a date; placing it in a temporary table,then I picked CS101 and will check in temporary table whether the RollNumbers of this Coursecode matches any other RollNumber of other Coursecode in the temporary table.

```
---------------------
    Code    Date
---------------------
    CS101    1
    CS201    2
    ME102    1
    PT101    3
```

My code:

- `#temp3` contains all data (CourseCodes, RollNumbers)
- `#mytemp1` ( Output Data)

and cursor contains the Distinct coursecodes

```
SET @cursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT coursecode
FROM #temp3
ORDER BY CourseCode

OPEN @cursor
FETCH NEXT
FROM @cursor INTO @cursorid


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN 

        BEGIN
            SET @j=1
            WHILE(@j !=9999999) 
            BEGIN 

                IF( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp3 WHERE CourseCode = @cursorid AND RegdNo IN (
                    SELECT  RegdNo FROM #temp3 WHERE CourseCode IN ( SELECT coursecode FROM #myTemp1 WHERE counter1 = @j)
                )) = 0
                        BEGIN
                            INSERT INTO #myTemp1 VALUES (@cursorid,@j)
                            SET @j=9999999
                        END
                ELSE   
                BEGIN
                        SET @j = @j + 1
                END 
            END
    END

FETCH NEXT
FROM @cursor INTO @cursorid
END
CLOSE @cursor
DEALLOCATE @cursor
```

This code is working fine but taking too much time( 4110222 records)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: We can use CTE to do this efficiently. will work up an example for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74330/discussion-between-kanwar-kakkar-and-ughai).

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code. I believe that you have error in output and `CS101` should precede `CS201`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( Roll INT, Code CHAR(5) )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1011, 'CS201' ),
        ( 2213, 'CS201' ),
        ( 3312, 'CS101' ),
        ( 4000, 'CS201' ),
        ( 1011, 'CS101' ),
        ( 5312, 'ME102' ),
        ( 1011, 'PT101' ),
        ( 3319, 'ME102' );

WITH    cte1
          AS ( SELECT   code ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Code ) AS rn
               FROM     @t
               GROUP BY code
             ),
        cte2
          AS ( SELECT   code ,
                        rn ,
                        1 AS Date
               FROM     cte1
               WHERE    rn = 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   c1.code ,
                        c1.rn ,
                        CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT   *
                                           FROM     @t a
                                                    JOIN @t b ON a.Roll = b.Roll
                                                    JOIN cte1 c ON c.rn < c1.rn
                                                              AND b.Code = c.code
                                           WHERE    a.code = c1.code ) THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                        END
               FROM     cte1 c1
                        JOIN cte2 c2 ON c1.rn = c2.rn + 1
             ),
        cte3
          AS ( SELECT   Code ,
                        CASE WHEN Date = 0 THEN 1
                             ELSE SUM(Date) OVER ( ORDER BY rn )
                        END AS Date
               FROM     cte2
             )
    SELECT  * FROM    cte3
```

Output:

```
Code    Date
CS101   1
CS201   2
ME102   1
PT101   3
```

EDIT:

`cte1` will return:

```
code    rn
CS101   1
CS201   2
ME102   3
PT101   4
```

The main work is done in `cte2`. It is recursive common table expression.
First you take top 1 row from `cte1`:

```
SELECT   code ,
         rn ,
         1 AS Date
         FROM     cte1
         WHERE    rn = 1
```

Then the recursion progresses:

You are joining `cte1` on `cte2` and pick following rns (2, 3...) and check if there are any rolls in `CS201` that match rolls in previous codes(`CS101`) in first step, check if there any rolls in `ME102` that match rolls in previous codes(`CS101, CS201`) in second step etc. If exists you return 1 else 0:

```
code    rn  Date
CS101   1   1
CS201   2   1
ME102   3   0
PT101   4   1
```

Last `cte3` does the following: if Date = 0 then return 1, else return sum of Dates in previous rows including current row.

**EDIT1:**

Since my understanding was incorrect here is one more statement:

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   code ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Code ) AS rn
               FROM     @t
               GROUP BY code
             )

  SELECT co.Code,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ISNULL(o.Code, co.Code)) AS Date
           FROM cte     co
  OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 ci.Code 
              FROM cte ci 
              WHERE ci.rn < co.rn AND 
              NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @t 
                         WHERE code = ci.code AND 
                         roll IN(SELECT roll FROM @t WHERE code = co.code)) ORDER BY ci.rn) o
  ORDER BY co.rn
```

Output:

```
Code    Date
CS101   1
CS201   2
ME102   1
PT101   2
```

**EDIT2:**

This is insane but, here is code that seems to work:

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY roll ORDER BY Code ) AS Date
               FROM     @t
             )
    SELECT  Code ,
            MAX(Date) AS Date
    FROM    cte
    GROUP BY Code
```